# Creating several react-select with cycle

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to render a several blocks that have to contain select written with [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select). And when i change value one of them they all change their value. 
I know that problem in key of state but i can't imagine how to make select change by another way.

```
const options = [ 
    {value: 'test1', label: 'First Text'},{value: 'test2', label: 'Second Text'}
]

class Selects extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selected : options[0]
    }
  }

  changeHandler(option) {
    this.setState({
      selected : option.value
    })
  }

  drawSelects(){
    let numberOfSelects = 3;
    let selects = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfSelects; i++) {
      selects.push(
        <Select
          value={this.state.selected}
          options={options}
          onChange={this.changeHandler.bind(this)}
          searchable={false}
          clearable={false}
        />
        )
    }
    return selects;
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.drawSelects()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

P.S. The main target is adding new Select with same options when user click on special button. So i have a counter of selects and thx to this counter i'm trying to draw the right amount of selects

Comment: Have 3 of your "Selects" components inside an other parent component ? for somewhere else ? Right now the 3 selects are all inside the same component meaning they share the same state/props...

Comment: @WilomGfx let say we have 1 main component Selects, and we have to generate here several <Select/>

Comment: ok well in this case make your self a custom select component that is just a react-select component but it has its own state and your Selects has the container for all your select.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are passing the same value to all your selects.
Try with something like (not tested)

```
class Selects extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selected : [0, 1]
    }
  }

  changeHandler(option) {
    const newSelectedOptions = this.state.selected; // This will mutate the original state, consider using _.clone or something like that
    newSelectedOptions[option.id] = option.value;
    this.setState({
      selected: newSelectedOptions
    })
  }

  drawSelects(){
    let numberOfSelects = 3;
    let selects = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfSelects; i++) {
      selects.push(
        <Select
          id={i}
          value={options[this.state.selected[i]]}
          options={options}
          onChange={this.changeHandler.bind(this)}
          searchable={false}
          clearable={false}
        />
        )
    }
    return selects;
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.drawSelects()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: solution of  WilomGfx is better, but thanks for your answer

Comment: I agree! Don't hesitate if there's anything else